# Webpack imports from entry file, not available in dist/index.html

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have imports in index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from "axios";
import jQuery from "jQuery";
window.Vue = Vue;
var $ = jQuery;

Vue.use(axios);

export {$, Vue};
```

Then in my dist folder i have an index.html loading the main.js file that webpack outputs

```
   <div id="app">
        
   </div>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
   <script>
    console.log(Vue);
    console.log(window.Vue);
   </script>
```

Obviously I have access to window.Vue, but why don't I have access to just Vue?

Im new to webpack.  Is there something i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

`export` doesn't implicitly make properties available in the global scope, it allows them to be `import`ed elsewhere. If you want `$` and `Vue` attached to the window, you need to do that explicitly in `index.js`.

```js
window.Vue = Vue;
window.$ = $;
```

Comment: yeah, thats what I ended up doing.  But now I have a new problem.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351863/vue-js-showing-blank-page-after-init