# Vue.js showing blank page after init

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My webpack entry file

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
window.Vue = Vue;
```

Then my index.html

```html
<div>
  <div id="app">{{msg}} test</div>
</div>

<script>
  console.log(window.Vue);
  // This return a valid instance

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    new window.Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: { msg: 'Hello World!' }
    });
  })
</script>
```

This loads, I briefly see {{msg}} test flash on the screen, and the Vue replaces the view.  But its empty.  {{msg}} doesnt display Hello World.  But also "test" dissappears too, meaning it looks like the whole #app div gets replaced with empty content.

Whats happening here?
Strangest thing is if I include

```html
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Then it works.  But if I dont include it console.log(window.Vue) still shows a valid instance???  So it should work??  Its getting passed correctly from my entry file.

Never seen this before.  This is my first time using Vue.js outside of its normal cli context.  Im trying to integrate it into an old legacy jQuery project.

Comment: The main difference from the basic pattern [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering) is you have the load listener. What's that for?

Comment: Its to make sure the page is loaded.  Before I try do anything with Vue.  It works when I include the Vue script tag.  But when I dont it still "works", cuz it erases the content.  But the content is blank.  Im stumped.  So with the script tag, it replaces {{msg}} with hello world.  And without it window.Vue still returns a valid instance, but replaces all the content inside #app.  Even the "test" string.  Which it should not touch at all.

Comment: try and do ```window.app = new window.Vue(....```

Comment: I think `import Vue from 'vue';` does not load the template compiler (you might be server-side rendering, so you could leave the compiler out of runtime), but `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>` does import it. Any reason why you can't just add the unpkg script to the header?

Comment: @RichardMatsen Yeah, because Im trying to use Vue.js in a javaFX webview.  So I want the script that I load, to just be one main.js script.  For easy loading.  And I cant include script tags in a javaFX webview.   But you are correct.... I just added import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js' and now it works.  Cuz Im including the compiler.  Tahnks!